# assign color animation Three.js with tween.js

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, tween.js

```
var color="#FF0000";
function hexToR(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(0,2),16)}
function hexToG(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(2,4),16)}
function hexToB(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(4,6),16)}
function cutHex(h) {return (h.charAt(0)=="#") ? h.substring(1,7):h}   
new TWEEN.Tween( municipios[i].material.color ).to( { r: hexToR(color), g:hexToG(color), b:hexToB(color) }, 5000 ).start();
```

I happen to have a value in hexadecimal, convert it to him in rgb, and whenever a problem occurs put the converted value in the transition. For example I have "# FF0000" rgb that is 255,0,0 and if I try to put the 255,0,0 have problems. Reading the documentation says Three.js r, g, b only receives values between 0 and 1. What can I do?

Comment: you can divide by 255

Answer (score -3):

you can try this code.

Sorry for the bad approximation...

```
if(color==1) color = 0.00392156862745;
if(color==2) color = 0.0078431372549;
if(color==3) color = 0.0117647058824;
if(color==4) color = 0.0156862745098;
if(color==5) color = 0.0196078431373;
if(color==6) color = 0.0235294117647;
if(color==7) color = 0.0274509803922;
if(color==8) color = 0.0313725490196;
if(color==9) color = 0.0352941176471;
if(color==10) color = 0.0392156862745;
if(color==11) color = 0.043137254902;
if(color==12) color = 0.0470588235294;
if(color==13) color = 0.0509803921569;
if(color==14) color = 0.0549019607843;
if(color==15) color = 0.0588235294118;
if(color==16) color = 0.0627450980392;
if(color==17) color = 0.0666666666667;
if(color==18) color = 0.0705882352941;
if(color==19) color = 0.0745098039216;
if(color==20) color = 0.078431372549;
if(color==21) color = 0.0823529411765;
if(color==22) color = 0.0862745098039;
if(color==23) color = 0.0901960784314;
if(color==24) color = 0.0941176470588;
if(color==25) color = 0.0980392156863;
if(color==26) color = 0.101960784314;
if(color==27) color = 0.105882352941;
if(color==28) color = 0.109803921569;
if(color==29) color = 0.113725490196;
if(color==30) color = 0.117647058824;
if(color==31) color = 0.121568627451;
if(color==32) color = 0.125490196078;
if(color==33) color = 0.129411764706;
if(color==34) color = 0.133333333333;
if(color==35) color = 0.137254901961;
if(color==36) color = 0.141176470588;
if(color==37) color = 0.145098039216;
if(color==38) color = 0.149019607843;
if(color==39) color = 0.152941176471;
if(color==40) color = 0.156862745098;
if(color==41) color = 0.160784313725;
if(color==42) color = 0.164705882353;
if(color==43) color = 0.16862745098;
if(color==44) color = 0.172549019608;
if(color==45) color = 0.176470588235;
if(color==46) color = 0.180392156863;
if(color==47) color = 0.18431372549;
if(color==48) color = 0.188235294118;
if(color==49) color = 0.192156862745;
if(color==50) color = 0.196078431373;
if(color==51) color = 0.2;
if(color==52) color = 0.203921568627;
if(color==53) color = 0.207843137255;
if(color==54) color = 0.211764705882;
if(color==55) color = 0.21568627451;
if(color==56) color = 0.219607843137;
if(color==57) color = 0.223529411765;
if(color==58) color = 0.227450980392;
if(color==59) color = 0.23137254902;
if(color==60) color = 0.235294117647;
if(color==61) color = 0.239215686275;
if(color==62) color = 0.243137254902;
if(color==63) color = 0.247058823529;
if(color==64) color = 0.250980392157;
if(color==65) color = 0.254901960784;
if(color==66) color = 0.258823529412;
if(color==67) color = 0.262745098039;
if(color==68) color = 0.266666666667;
if(color==69) color = 0.270588235294;
if(color==70) color = 0.274509803922;
if(color==71) color = 0.278431372549;
if(color==72) color = 0.282352941176;
if(color==73) color = 0.286274509804;
if(color==74) color = 0.290196078431;
if(color==75) color = 0.294117647059;
if(color==76) color = 0.298039215686;
if(color==77) color = 0.301960784314;
if(color==78) color = 0.305882352941;
if(color==79) color = 0.309803921569;
if(color==80) color = 0.313725490196;
if(color==81) color = 0.317647058824;
if(color==82) color = 0.321568627451;
if(color==83) color = 0.325490196078;
if(color==84) color = 0.329411764706;
if(color==85) color = 0.333333333333;
if(color==86) color = 0.337254901961;
if(color==87) color = 0.341176470588;
if(color==88) color = 0.345098039216;
if(color==89) color = 0.349019607843;
if(color==90) color = 0.352941176471;
if(color==91) color = 0.356862745098;
if(color==92) color = 0.360784313725;
if(color==93) color = 0.364705882353;
if(color==94) color = 0.36862745098;
if(color==95) color = 0.372549019608;
if(color==96) color = 0.376470588235;
if(color==97) color = 0.380392156863;
if(color==98) color = 0.38431372549;
if(color==99) color = 0.388235294118;
if(color==100) color = 0.392156862745;
if(color==101) color = 0.396078431373;
if(color==102) color = 0.4;
if(color==103) color = 0.403921568627;
if(color==104) color = 0.407843137255;
if(color==105) color = 0.411764705882;
if(color==106) color = 0.41568627451;
if(color==107) color = 0.419607843137;
if(color==108) color = 0.423529411765;
if(color==109) color = 0.427450980392;
if(color==110) color = 0.43137254902;
if(color==111) color = 0.435294117647;
if(color==112) color = 0.439215686275;
if(color==113) color = 0.443137254902;
if(color==114) color = 0.447058823529;
if(color==115) color = 0.450980392157;
if(color==116) color = 0.454901960784;
if(color==117) color = 0.458823529412;
if(color==118) color = 0.462745098039;
if(color==119) color = 0.466666666667;
if(color==120) color = 0.470588235294;
if(color==121) color = 0.474509803922;
if(color==122) color = 0.478431372549;
if(color==123) color = 0.482352941176;
if(color==124) color = 0.486274509804;
if(color==125) color = 0.490196078431;
if(color==126) color = 0.494117647059;
if(color==127) color = 0.498039215686;
if(color==128) color = 0.501960784314;
if(color==129) color = 0.505882352941;
if(color==130) color = 0.509803921569;
if(color==131) color = 0.513725490196;
if(color==132) color = 0.517647058824;
if(color==133) color = 0.521568627451;
if(color==134) color = 0.525490196078;
if(color==135) color = 0.529411764706;
if(color==136) color = 0.533333333333;
if(color==137) color = 0.537254901961;
if(color==138) color = 0.541176470588;
if(color==139) color = 0.545098039216;
if(color==140) color = 0.549019607843;
if(color==141) color = 0.552941176471;
if(color==142) color = 0.556862745098;
if(color==143) color = 0.560784313725;
if(color==144) color = 0.564705882353;
if(color==145) color = 0.56862745098;
if(color==146) color = 0.572549019608;
if(color==147) color = 0.576470588235;
if(color==148) color = 0.580392156863;
if(color==149) color = 0.58431372549;
if(color==150) color = 0.588235294118;
if(color==151) color = 0.592156862745;
if(color==152) color = 0.596078431373;
if(color==153) color = 0.6;
if(color==154) color = 0.603921568627;
if(color==155) color = 0.607843137255;
if(color==156) color = 0.611764705882;
if(color==157) color = 0.61568627451;
if(color==158) color = 0.619607843137;
if(color==159) color = 0.623529411765;
if(color==160) color = 0.627450980392;
if(color==161) color = 0.63137254902;
if(color==162) color = 0.635294117647;
if(color==163) color = 0.639215686275;
if(color==164) color = 0.643137254902;
if(color==165) color = 0.647058823529;
if(color==166) color = 0.650980392157;
if(color==167) color = 0.654901960784;
if(color==168) color = 0.658823529412;
if(color==169) color = 0.662745098039;
if(color==170) color = 0.666666666667;
if(color==171) color = 0.670588235294;
if(color==172) color = 0.674509803922;
if(color==173) color = 0.678431372549;
if(color==174) color = 0.682352941176;
if(color==175) color = 0.686274509804;
if(color==176) color = 0.690196078431;
if(color==177) color = 0.694117647059;
if(color==178) color = 0.698039215686;
if(color==179) color = 0.701960784314;
if(color==180) color = 0.705882352941;
if(color==181) color = 0.709803921569;
if(color==182) color = 0.713725490196;
if(color==183) color = 0.717647058824;
if(color==184) color = 0.721568627451;
if(color==185) color = 0.725490196078;
if(color==186) color = 0.729411764706;
if(color==187) color = 0.733333333333;
if(color==188) color = 0.737254901961;
if(color==189) color = 0.741176470588;
if(color==190) color = 0.745098039216;
if(color==191) color = 0.749019607843;
if(color==192) color = 0.752941176471;
if(color==193) color = 0.756862745098;
if(color==194) color = 0.760784313725;
if(color==195) color = 0.764705882353;
if(color==196) color = 0.76862745098;
if(color==197) color = 0.772549019608;
if(color==198) color = 0.776470588235;
if(color==199) color = 0.780392156863;
if(color==200) color = 0.78431372549;
if(color==201) color = 0.788235294118;
if(color==202) color = 0.792156862745;
if(color==203) color = 0.796078431373;
if(color==204) color = 0.8;
if(color==205) color = 0.803921568627;
if(color==206) color = 0.807843137255;
if(color==207) color = 0.811764705882;
if(color==208) color = 0.81568627451;
if(color==209) color = 0.819607843137;
if(color==210) color = 0.823529411765;
if(color==211) color = 0.827450980392;
if(color==212) color = 0.83137254902;
if(color==213) color = 0.835294117647;
if(color==214) color = 0.839215686275;
if(color==215) color = 0.843137254902;
if(color==216) color = 0.847058823529;
if(color==217) color = 0.850980392157;
if(color==218) color = 0.854901960784;
if(color==219) color = 0.858823529412;
if(color==220) color = 0.862745098039;
if(color==221) color = 0.866666666667;
if(color==222) color = 0.870588235294;
if(color==223) color = 0.874509803922;
if(color==224) color = 0.878431372549;
if(color==225) color = 0.882352941176;
if(color==226) color = 0.886274509804;
if(color==227) color = 0.890196078431;
if(color==228) color = 0.894117647059;
if(color==229) color = 0.898039215686;
if(color==230) color = 0.901960784314;
if(color==231) color = 0.905882352941;
if(color==232) color = 0.909803921569;
if(color==233) color = 0.913725490196;
if(color==234) color = 0.917647058824;
if(color==235) color = 0.921568627451;
if(color==236) color = 0.925490196078;
if(color==237) color = 0.929411764706;
if(color==238) color = 0.933333333333;
if(color==239) color = 0.937254901961;
if(color==240) color = 0.941176470588;
if(color==241) color = 0.945098039216;
if(color==242) color = 0.949019607843;
if(color==243) color = 0.952941176471;
if(color==244) color = 0.956862745098;
if(color==245) color = 0.960784313725;
if(color==246) color = 0.964705882353;
if(color==247) color = 0.96862745098;
if(color==248) color = 0.972549019608;
if(color==249) color = 0.976470588235;
if(color==250) color = 0.980392156863;
if(color==251) color = 0.98431372549;
if(color==252) color = 0.988235294118;
if(color==253) color = 0.992156862745;
if(color==254) color = 0.996078431373;
if(color==255) color = 1.0;
```

and, of course, if color is zero, you can leave the value as is..